# ICE Server to actively refuse connections

Tags: ice

I am looking for the equivalent of HTTP 503 (or 500.13) on ICE. Is there such thing?

We have a server that has to process requests in certain time. We do have the proper timeouts on the client but there are cases where the server knows that it will not get to the request in time and needs to signal that to the customer without the wait. Is there a way to achieve that in ICE?

Answer (score 0):

In ICE, this could be accomplished a couple of different ways depending on how you want it handled on the client. For example, one could throw an exception on the server(which is propagated to the client) indicating a timeout or server full condition. The other option is to wrap your responses in a state structure, allowing the client to check the state on response. Without knowing the specifics of your slice structures it's difficult to get any more specific.